# Is it safe to close shell just by clicking "X" or using "ctrl+d"?

Tags: shell, terminal, security, root, exit

Is it safe to close shell just by clicking "X" or using "ctrl+d" while logged in as root with su or is it safer to close it by typing "exit"? Is there any difference (security-wise) at all or is it the same and it does not matter which way you use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ctrl-D or `exit` is the same.

If you using the "X", the window manager sends a terminate signal to the shell.
Which has at the end the same result. If the shell does not react, the user usually gets a warning and can then force the shell to end (equal to `kill -9 $PID`).

There is one small difference between the "X"- and exit-method if you are using `zsh` as shell: If you have a background process running, `exit`/ctrl-D produces the first time only a warning message "you have running jobs", the second time the shell is closed. With the "X" button, the shell terminates immediately without any warnings.

Comment: Also there is a difference in bash as well. If you ctrl+d, then any processes backgrounded with `&` will remain running. If you "X", then they'll get terminated.

Comment: @Patrick this seems to depend on the terminal emulator rather than the shell. Unless the emulator explicitly kills backgrounded processes, as far as I am aware bash won’t send them SIGHUP no matter how you exit. I just tried this on Mac OS X 10.7.3. Terminal doesn’t kill the backgrounded processes, but Xterm (running in X11) does. I don’t know whether that’s a behavior of Xterm specifically or X11 generally.

Comment: @jofel this is not true, see my answer.

Comment: @Patrick thanks for pointing this out. I'll edit or delete my answer.

Comment: @jofel nah, dont delete, the zsh info is still useful. I'm only a noob at zsh, so I cant comment there. But that does bring up a good point, so I edited my answer to note that different shells can behave differently, and the default behavior I described is bash dependent, while the OP doesnt specify his shell.

Answer (score 7):

Closing the terminal emulator is not the same as pressing `CTRL + D` (unless the option `huponexit` is set).

- When you close the terminal (clicking "X"), the terminal emulator sends a SIGHUP to the shell. When bash receives a SIGHUP, it also sends a SIGHUP to all your jobs.
- When you exit the terminal with `CTRL+D` or `logout` or `exit`, the shell exits without sending a SIGHUP to all the jobs. This is the default behavior, but can be changed by setting the bash `shopt` setting  `huponexit`.

So ultimately if your goal is to make sure there's nothing running in the background, its safter to click "X".

.

The info provided by jofel in his comment is incorrect (sorry jofel). The terminal emulator has no clue what jobs are running under the shell, thus it cant terminate them.

**NOTE**:
This behavior is completely dependent upon the shell. It is entirely possible that different shells have different default behaviors.

Comment: When `Ctrl+d` process is inherited by PPID 1 = systemd

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. So much that, when you press ^D, you are doing the same thing as typing 'exit':

```
$ su -
Password:
# [press ^D]
logout
```

Comment: Yes, `CTRL+D` and `exit` are the same, the question was about clicking the window manager's "X" to close the window, not typing `exit` :-)